# How to load Jar file in my program?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that load classes and jar files  .My app handle the plus operator  .For this I have 2 class and one jar file  :

1- Operator interface jar file in directory D:\operatorAPI (Operator interface is a jar file)

```
package OperatorAPI;

public interface Operator
{
    int calculate(int num1 , int num2);
}
```

2-class Plus in directory (D:\operators)

```
package operators;

import OperatorAPI.*;

public class Plus implements Operator
{
    public int calculate(int num1 , int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

3- Main class in directory D:\source\main  :

```
package source.main;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import operatorAPI.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("D:\\");
        URI uri = file.toURI();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL}
        ClassLoader classloader = new URLClassLoader (urls);
        Class clazz = classloader.loadClass("operator.Plus");

        Operator instance = (Operator) clazz.newInstance();
        int output = instance.calculate(10,20);
        System.out.println("The result is :" + output);
    }
}
```

But when I run my Program in command line I get this exception  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: operatorAPI/Operator

I think because Operator interface is a jar file I should load it to my program But I don't know How to do this  .
Can anyone help me?

Comment: is D:\operatorAPI added to the classpath ?

Comment: All you're doing is adding the `D:\` drive to the class loader, you're not actually loading any Jar files

Comment: yes I run this way : java -cp Operator.jar  source/main/Main.My teacher said I should load Operator.jar in the Main class But I don't know how to do this

Comment: @MadProgrammer How load jar file in my program?

Comment: Pass a valid reference to one or more `Jar` files, not just a directory.  A directory simply suggests that there are class files within the directory, it won't magically load jars within it

Comment: java -cp D:/operatorAPI/Operator.jar ...

Comment: I do all of this  .but the teacher said that I should load jar files in may code not in runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to load the operators (Plus etc.) dynamically. If you have the operator classes under 'D:\', the way you are loading is correct. However, your interface 'Operator' in the JAR itself is not loaded. The `Plus` operator depends on this interface and expects it to be loaded. Adding the operator.jar file to your class path should solve the problem.

If you want to load the 'Operator.jar' also dynamically, update the urls passing to the URLClassLoader.

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL, new File("PathtoOperator.jar").toURI().toURL() }
```

This should resolve the error you are receiving.

Comment: I add in compile time but not solved  . java -cp Operator.jar source/main/Main

Comment: Is Operator.jar file in the directory from where you are executing the java command?

Comment: @ KDM Yes  .the teacher said that I sould load jar file in the code but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: you mean I should have 2 classloader ? 1- URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL, new File("operators.Plus").toURI().toURL() }                                          2-URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL, new File("PathtoOperator.jar").toURI().toURL() }

Comment: No just pass the URL for the jar also to the classloader you are constructing.

Comment: i'm so so sorry  .I'm new in java I can't understand your mean  .

Comment: Change `URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL()}` to `URL[] urls = new URL[] { uri.toURL(), new File("path-to-jar").toURI().toURL() };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89553/discussion-between-soha-and-kdm).

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're only using `D:\` in your classpath:

```
File file = new File("D:\\");
URI uri = file.toURI();
URL[] urls = new URL[] {uri.toURL}
ClassLoader classloader = new URLClassLoader (urls);
```

If you want to use a jar file, you should specify that:

```
File file = new File("D:\\operator.jar");
```

If that's *all* you need your new classloader to load, that should be the only change you need. You might want to make this a command-line argument, mind you.

As you use `Operator` within your "driver" class, you'll need that in the classpath you run with though. For example:

```
java -cp operatorAPI.jar;. source.main.Main
```

You shouldn't need to add `operator.jar` to the classpath when *compiling* though... if the idea is to write a "pluggable" system, others should be able to add plugins without you knowing anything about them at compile time. Both your code and the plugins should just know about the shared interface.

Comment: I should load both Plus class and jar file

Comment: @soha: The `Plus` class is *in* the jar file (`operator.jar`) isn't it? If not, I'll edit.

Comment: no Plus class is in the seprate package (D:\\operators.Plus)

Comment: @soha: You're getting very confused between class names, filenames, package names, and jar files. In the comments you said that you needed to use `operator.jar`, so I assumed that's where `Plus` is - there's *also* `operatorAPI.jar` which contains the interface. You need to be *very* clear in what you're asking or it's really, really hard to help you.

Comment: yes you are right I'm new in java and I don't know many rules  .I have  :     1- an interface in operatorAPI package(d:\operatorAPI.Operator)  2- Plus class in operators package (d:\operators.Plus)  3- and the Main Class in source.main package (d:\source.main.Main)  .Now in my Main class I should load both interface and Plus class

Comment: @soha: `d:\operatorAPI.Operator` isn't a package. It *might* be a directory, but I suspect not. It would be really helpful if you could edit your question to show all the files involved - both source files and jar files.